# git eol, reset, and strange behavior

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I'm using git on Windows 2.9.3.windows.1
I cloned my repository and noticed that without doing anything a set of files in a particular directory were modified.  I figured it was some problem with code.autocrlf (set to true by default on Windows).  So I tried a few different settings without luck.

But, the really strange thing is that when I do this:

```
rm -rf web/*
git reset --hard
git status
```

I get a set of files that are modified, not necessarily the same ones as when I cloned. Repeating those three commands I get yet a different set of files without doing anything in between.  Repeat again I get a yet different set of files (FWIW it appears there are 3 different sets that are modified).  This is independent of the value of the core.autocrlf setting and whether it is global or local. kdiff3 reports a sampling of the files (via an invocation of difftool) as being binary equal.

Ultimately I am interested in not having modified files when I clone a repository but I can't figure out what the setting should be if the results keep changing.

What am I not understanding?

Thanks for any help.

[edit - additional info]
I cloned in a separate directory and repeated the problem with different sets of files showing as being modified after a git reset --hard.  I committed the changes.  After another rm -rf web/*, git reset --hard I got the longest list of changed files. After committing those "changes" I tried again.  Now the git status comes up clean and repeated attempts don't produce modified files.

Comment: Without more detail I can't be more specific (and I don't really want to spend a lot of time debugging your repositories :-) ), but there are two sources of this kind of problem on Windows since it is, by default, case-*in*sensitive about file names. On Linux, file `a.txt` is quite different from file `A.TXT`, but on Windows, these are the same file. So it might be CR/LF issues, or it might be two different files with names that become conflated; or even a mix of both.

Comment: I get that there would be some differences because of these reasons (core.ignorecase=true, BTW).  But, under what conditions would successive invocations of rm/git reset --hard/git status (without any intervening commands) yield different sets of files that are modified?

Comment: That's a bit of a mystery, but I've seen it happen with case folding on the Mac: something to do with Git getting confused about which files are where. The core.ignorecase makes it *try* to deal with this but it just doesn't seem to work right. I never pushed further on the problem, I just did my work on a non-case-folding system.

Comment: Looks like removing * text=auto in .gitattributes solves this problem.  I've seen comments about this in other threads but I was hung up on the non-deterministic nature of this.  If I didn't know better I would suspect an uninitialized variable somewhere :-)